# C Pattern Code: Why this code for printing Star-Pyramid is not working?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am not able to figure out why below code for printing Star-Pyramid is not giving required output? Can anyone tell me where I go wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Input height: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++);
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= 2 * n - 1; j++)
        {
            if ((j >= n - i + 1) && (j <= n + i - 1))
            {
                printf("*");

            }
            else
            {
                printf("");

            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input height:
```

After specifying height, e.g., 5.

```
Input height: 5
```

Console Output:

```
Input height: 5
*********
```

Expected Output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Comment: `printf("")` doesn't print anything. Did you mean `printf(" ")`?

Comment: not compiling in egyptian mode?

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: You have a typo here: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++);` The `;` at the end means that the body of the loop is empty. The rest of the code is executed just once after the loop finishes.

Comment: `void main(void)` is not a correct declaration, it should be `int main()`.

Comment: Turn on full compiler warnings. My compiler noticed both of those problems.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is printf(" "); .

Comment: Fixing the typos makes the program work correctly.

Comment: @Bramar Thanks! Now it is working.

Comment: once again I vote for c compilers to default to -Wall -Werror.

Comment: @GirishKumar Please don't fix the code in question to make it pointless. If you want to show the correct code, you are free to answer your own question.

Comment: @Barmar As I have `;` at the end of `for(i=1;i<=n;i++);`. Can it be explained how program is even able to print `2*n-1` `*`?

Comment: @GirishKumar That semicolon doesn't keep the next block beginning with `for(j=1;j<=2*n-1;j++)` from being executed. Its just not executed in a loop.

Comment: @Swordfish but here is also `if` condition under `for(j=1;j<=2*n-1;j++)` loop.

Comment: @GirishKumar Yes? Where is the problem with that? `i` is `n` after the first `for`-loop.

Comment: @Swordfish My basics are really weak. Can you suggest me how should I start learning Programming.

Comment: @GirishKumar I put your code in my answer and added comments. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with comments:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main(void)  // main returns int. always *)
> {
>     int n, i, j;
>
>     printf("Input height: ");
>     scanf("%d", &n);  // lets assume we input 5
>
>     for (i = 1; i <= n; i++);  // i gets incremented until it is greater than n --> i = 6, n = 5
>
>     // following lines not indented cause not part of for-loop above.
>     { // <-- just a new block beginning, nothing special
>     for (j = 1; j <= 2 * n - 1; j++)  // will increment j till it reaches 2*n-1 = 9 with n = 5
>     {
>         // n - i = -1, -1 + 1 =  0, j starts at 1 --> (j >= n - i + 1) always true.
>         // n + i = 11, 11 + 1 = 12, j runs till 9 --> (j <= n + i - 1) always true.
>         if ((j >= n - i + 1) && (j <= n + i - 1))
>         {
>             printf("*");  // will run 9 times
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             printf("");  // never.
>
>         }
>         }
>         printf("\n");
>     }
> }
> ```

<sup>*)</sup> Except on freestanding environments, which should be of no concern for you in the near feature.

Short version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = 0;
    printf("Input height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    for (int h = height; h > 0; --h) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * height - h; ++i) {
            putchar("* "[i < h]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Explanation:

```
height = 8
h = height ... 1                                          2 x
                            h - 1                        height - h
h = 8: 1234567*           7 spaces,  1 star,   8 total = 2 * 8  - 8
h = 7: 123456***          6 spaces,  3 stars,  9 total = 2 * 8  - 7
h = 6: 12345*****         5 spaces,  5 stars, 10 total = 2 * 8  - 6
h = 5: 1234*******        4 spaces,  7 stars, 11 total = 2 * 8  - 5
h = 4: 123*********       3 spaces,  9 stars, 12 total = 2 * 8  - 4
h = 3: 12***********      2 spaces, 11 stars, 13 total = 2 * 8  - 3
h = 2: 1*************     1 space,  13 stars, 14 total = 2 * 8  - 2
h = 1: ***************    0 spaces, 15 stars, 15 total = 2 * 8  - 1
```

As you see the count of spaces is simply `h - 1`.
The total number of characters for each line is `2 * height - h`.

So in the inner `for` loop, we count from `1` to `2 * height - h` ... the total number of chars. For `i < h` we print spaces, for higher values of `i` we print stars.

`"* "[i < h]` could also be written as `i < h ? ' ' : '*'`
or even more verbose:

```
if(i < h) {
    putchar(' ');
} else {
    putchar('*');
}
```

Comment: I think `i` will get incremented to `n + 1`.

Comment: @GirishKumar Is my explanation helping somewhat?

Comment: @Swordfish Yes your explanation is very insightful.

Comment: @GirishKumar Very observant ;) changed.

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution for pattern printing

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = n - i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
      printf(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
      printf("*");
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < i; l++) {
      printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
6
```

Output:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Comment: Yes, It is also correct, I am not only able to figure out why mine is not working. A kind user @Barmar have already pointed out my mistake.